# Magento 2: Set Cache life time to block

Tags: magento2.3, cache, block-cache, product-view-page, product-lables

I am creating an extension for displaying labels in product page and listing page. Everything works fine except the cache issue. If I set the status to inactive, then the labels will display in the frontend until I clear the cache. 
How can I automatically display/off these?

Here is my code.

Layout XML

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\ProductLabel\Block\Productlabel" name="product.label" template="Company_ProductLabel::productlabel.phtml"  />
 </referenceContainer>
```

Phtml

```
<?php 
if($block->isActive()):
    $productStickerBlock = $block->setStickerHTML();
?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*":{
            "viewPageSticker":{
                "imageTag": {
                  "imagePath": "<?php echo $productStickerBlock; ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<?php endif;  ?>
```

Block

```
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;


class Productlabel extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    protected $product = null;

    protected $coreRegistry;
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $collectionFactory;
    private $scopeConfig;
    private $_regularPrice;
    private $_finalPrice;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Company\ProductLabel\Model\ResourceModel\Productlabel\Grid\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $context->getScopeConfig();
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->addData([
                'cache_lifetime' => 360
            ]);

    }

    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $productId = $this->_getProduct()?$this->_getProduct()->getId() : null;
        $mode = 'cat' ;
        if($productId) {
          $mode = 'prod';
        }

        return [
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            $this->_design->getDesignTheme()->getId(),
            $mode,
            rand(),
            $productId
        ];
    }



    protected function _getProduct()
    {
        if (!$this->product) {
            $this->product = $this->coreRegistry->registry('product');
        }

        return $this->product;
    }

    public function isActive()
    {
       $active = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'company_productlabel/general/enable',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        if ($active) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
     public function setStickerHTML()
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();

        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                      ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1)
                      ->addFieldToFilter( array('from_date'),   array( array(   array('lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),  array('null' => true))))
                      ->addFieldToFilter( array('to_date'),   array( array(  array('gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),  array('null' => true))))
                       ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $this->_getProduct()->getId());

        $html = '';
        if($collection->getSize()) {
            $discount =  '' ;
            $html = "";
            foreach($collection as $label){                 
                $html .= "<div class='productsticker-wrapper ".$label->getLabelPosition()."'><img class='productlabelImage' src='".$this->getUrl('pub/media').$label->getImagePath()."' /></div>";             
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }


}
```

Require Js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            viewPageSticker: 'Company_ProductLabel/js/viewPageSticker'
        }
    }
};
```

JS File

```
define(
    [
        'jquery'
    ],
    function ($) {
        $.widget(
            'company.viewPageSticker',
            {
                _create: function () {
                    var self = this;
                    $(".product.media").append(self.options.imageTag.imagePath);
                }
            }
        );
        return $.company.viewPageSticker;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `'cache_lifetime' => null`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the FPC, you have to add cacheable = "false" in your block but it is not recommended.

```
<block class="Company\ProductLabel\Block\Productlabel" name="product.label" template="Company_ProductLabel::productlabel.phtml" cacheable="false" />
```

If you want to even surpass the FPC you have to add these labels via knockout JS or Ajax

Tell me if its clear? for you?